# Laravel PHPUnit: how to test url prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-testing

I'm learning to build some PHPUnit tests. My app redirects to default language when no prefix is used, for instance:
www.myapp.com has 301 redirect to www.myapp.com/en, while www.myapp.com/en has a 200 OK.

Trying to make tests to my Controller, i have the following code

```
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'HomeController@index');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
```

The response is 301 (because of this language prefix check). How can I test these controllers with prefix ? Thanks

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this property to your `tests/TestCase.php` file.

```php
// The base URL to use while testing the application.
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/en';
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this only applies to versions BEFORE Laravel 5.4.  See answer from @Moppo below.

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel 5.4 the `$baseUrl` method doesn't work anymore

You can set a custom root URL dinamycally in your tests with:

```php
\URL::forceRootUrl('http://www.myapp.com/en');
```